Fluid Dynamics through a Dynamic Lumen
Image:

*Photo by Springer Link
Problem:
Is there a way to model fluid flow through, what I am calling, a revolved sin wave lumen with the given parameters:

Starting with a known flow rate on a normal cylindrical lumen with the same height as max peaks of this revolved sin wave lumen (to put it visually, the revolved sin wave lumen appears marginally "pinched" in the troughs)
Known sin wave equation (period, amplitude, etc)
The hard part, a continuously traversing sin wave (moves A units about the x axis at a rate of ...)

Theoretics:

In an example where the lumen troughs each have a height of 0 (fully pinched) this turns into a peristaltic pump
Knowing that point above, can you have trough height greater than 0 (but less than the height of the peaks) to perform what I am calling partial peristaltic?

Question:

What is the change in flow rate given the varying sin wave, traversing period, starting flow rate, etc (will probably need to include characteristics of the fluid? Viscosity?)
Although with a slow traversing period, the fluid starts to decrease from original flow, what is the break even point with the traversing period where it flows the same in the normal lumen example?

Bonus:
Can a change in pressure can modeled?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
